# How can I add CORS on apigateway http_proxy without setting a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync

I have a API gateway and there are a few paths defined in the gateway. I'd like to enable CORS to one of the path which works as http_proxy pointing to an `appsync` in the backend. The appsync resolvers point to a dynamodb table. so frontend calls API gateway who pass the requests to appsync and the request is resolved by dynamodb.

My problem is to enable CORS on that particular path. But based on this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html it says I have to response the CORS header in backend which is a lambda. But I don't have a lambda in the backend. All the backends are just appsync + some resolvers (e.g. Dynamodb). How can I make it support CORS?

When I call appsync endpoint directly, it response `access-control-allow-origin: *` and it works fine for frontend (a web site). However, if the frontend calls API gateway domain, it will get rejected because of cors. I believe apigateway doesn't allow CORS so how can I enable cors in http_proxy integration without a backend lambda?

Comment: Did you follow these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html)? They don't say anything about lambda.

Comment: it only works for not `Lambda or HTTP proxy integrations`. You can check the doc in my question and move to bottom section

Comment: So you already know your answer. Probably your appsync backend has to implement fully cors handling.

Comment: right, the problem is my appsync backend doesn't have any source code. it is just dynamodb so that I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following `CloudFormation` declaration for your `GraphQL` based `HTTP_PROXY` integration for `POST` method

```
GraphQLPostMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      Rest of the properties for HTTP_PROXY integration
```

Define one more method for `OPTIONS` request. If the source i.e. `AppSync` responds to Options request with appropriate headers, you should be fine with a `HTTP_PROXY` integration. If it doesn't or you don't want to send the Options request to AppSync, in that case you can use the `MOCK` integration for the Options method.

```
GraphQLOptionsMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      ResourceId: !Ref <ReplaceWithYourResrouce>
      RestApiId: !Ref <ReplaceWithYourAPI>
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
          StatusCode: '200'
      Integration:
        Type: MOCK
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ''
            StatusCode: '200'
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Sub "'${ReplaceWithYourCORSAllowedOrigin}' or hardcode to *"
        PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
```

Comment: thanks for responding. why you set `true` for the reponse parameter under `MethodResponses` but set the real value in `integrationReponses`?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-methodresponse.html#cfn-apigateway-method-methodresponse-responseparameters The first one says it is required and in MOCK response you are sending the real value.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you put three single quote `'''` in the values?

Comment: Updated the quotes

Comment: My path has two method now, `POST` which is a http_proxy and `OPTIONS` is a mock.  when I enable cors it shows `invalid status code in response` and `invalid mapping expression specified` for `POST`. How can I skip `http_proxy` for above setting? It seems once I configure on the path, it apply to both OPTION and POST.

Comment: Can you share the template?